# How to create a line in a grid using Bresenham's line algorithm in Processing

Tags: algorithm, processing, bresenham

I want to create a line using Bresenham's [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) , but the only line that works is a horizontal line from left to right, lines pointing upwards do not work at all and lines drawn diagonally downwards appear in the wrong places, the more vertical the line, the more the distance between the mouse position changes and the drawn line up to a maximum of 3 cells. I'm using java and processing library. This is the link to all relevant [code](https://pastebin.com/NvThUhpp) . Main code is this:

```java
void lineDrawing()
{
  int deltaX = mouseNewCordX - mouseOldCordX, deltaY = mouseNewCordY - mouseOldCordY;
  int gradient = deltaY + deltaY, error = gradient - deltaX;

  if (abs(deltaY) < abs(deltaX))
  {
    if (mouseOldCordX > mouseNewCordX)
    {
      plotLineLow(mouseOldCordX, mouseOldCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    } else 
    {
      plotLineLow(mouseNewCordX, mouseNewCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    }
  } else 
  {
    if (mouseOldCordY > mouseNewCordY)
    {
      plotLineHigh(mouseOldCordX, mouseOldCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    } else
    {
      plotLineHigh(mouseNewCordX, mouseNewCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    }
  }
}

void plotLineLow(int x0, int y0, int deltaX, int deltaY, int gradient, int error)
{
  int yIncrease = 1;

  if (deltaY < 0)
  {
    yIncrease = -1;
    deltaY = -deltaY;
  }

  for (int x = mouseOldCordX; x <= mouseNewCordX; x += 1)
  {

    world[x][y0].state = selectedState;

    error += gradient;

    if (error >= 0)
    {
      y0 += yIncrease;
      error -= (deltaX + deltaX);
    }
  }
}

void plotLineHigh(int x0, int y0, int deltaX, int deltaY, int gradient, int error)
{
  int xIncrease = 1;

  if (deltaX < 0)
  {
    xIncrease = -1;
    deltaX = -deltaX;
  }

  for (int y = mouseOldCordY; y <= mouseNewCordY; y += 1)
  {

    world[x0][y].state = selectedState;

    error += gradient;

    if (error >= 0)
    {
      x0 += xIncrease;
      error -= (deltaY + deltaY);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are different Bresenham's line drawing for different things, but the most basic one needs to divide it into cases, where `dx>dy`, `dy>=dx`, because the accumulator only works on a certain range.

Comment: I have divided the code into appropriate cases:     ```  if (abs(deltaY) < abs(deltaX))
  {
    if (mouseOldCordX > mouseNewCordX)
    {
      plotLineLow(mouseOldCordX, mouseOldCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    } else 
    {
      plotLineLow(mouseNewCordX, mouseNewCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    }
  } else 
  {
    if (mouseOldCordY > mouseNewCordY)
    {
      plotLineHigh(mouseOldCordX, mouseOldCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    } else
    {
      plotLineHigh(mouseNewCordX, mouseNewCordY, deltaX, deltaY, gradient, error);
    }
  }```

Comment: I see. Hmm, where are you getting the initial value?

Comment: I'm getting inicial values from this: void mousePressed() 
{
  mouseOldCordX = mouseX/cellSize;
  mouseOldCordY = mouseY/cellSize;
  //world[mouseOldCordX][mouseOldCordY].state = selectedState;
}

void mouseReleased() 
{
  mouseNewCordX = mouseX/cellSize;
  mouseNewCordY = mouseY/cellSize;

  lineDrawing();
}

Comment: No, I mean, error should be initialized to half, it makes a better line. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#All_cases) has the full cases. (I don't know why someone downvoted you; I think this is a valid question.)

Comment: The method of initiating the error is irrelevant in this case. I know about wikipedia, I linked it under the algorithm.

Comment: True, the method just makes it even. I do notice that `error = dy + dy - dx` for all cases, I don't think that's right, but maybe it's not that important. Have you got it working for just one quadrant?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use wikipedia to create a code that works:

```java
    void lineDrawing()
    {
      int xIncrease = mouseOldCordX < mouseNewCordX ? 1 : -1;  
      int yIncrease = mouseOldCordY < mouseNewCordY ? 1 : -1;
      int deltaX =  abs(mouseNewCordX - mouseOldCordX);
      int deltaY = -abs(mouseNewCordY - mouseOldCordY);
      int error = deltaX + deltaY;
    
      while (true) 
      {
        world[mouseOldCordX][mouseOldCordY].state = selectedState;
    
        if ((mouseOldCordX == mouseNewCordX) && (mouseOldCordY == mouseNewCordY)) break;
    
        int doubleError = 2 * error;
    
        if (doubleError >= deltaY) 
        { 
          error += deltaY;
          mouseOldCordX += xIncrease;
        }
    
        if (doubleError <= deltaX)
        {
          error += deltaX;
          mouseOldCordY += yIncrease;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If of interest, there's an optimized version at https://sourceforge.net/p/wpbdc/rails/ci/master/tree/vendor/gems/WPBDC/ext/WPBDC/sketch.c

Comment: What is more optimized in this solution than in mine?

Comment: It's slight. Mine does 2 comparisons per inner loop. Yours does 3.  Incrementing/decrementing by constants rather than variables is potentially a bit faster. I just thought you might want to see there's more than one way to implement Bresenham.

Comment: There's also a version that works against the grain, it's more complicated, but faster still because it outputs multiple pixels at once.